# How to use v-select when items are related in Array

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-select

I have UI shows buttons from 3 different array, these datas are related, orders exchanges and parities , button have pre selected values , i need parities2 to be selected if exchange2 is selected.

```
<html>
<v-flex md4 sm4 >
        <v-select
            v-model="select7"
            :items="orders"
            flat solo
        ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 sm4 >
        <v-select
            v-model="select2"
            :items="exchanges"
            flat solo
        ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 sm4 >
        <v-select
            v-model="select3"
            :items="parities"
            flat solo
        ></v-select>
  </html>

  <script>
 data () {    
    select7:'o1',        
    orders: ['o1','o2'],
    select2:'ex1',
    select5:'ex1',
    select8:'ex2',
    exchanges: ['ex1','ex2'],
    select3:'par1',
    select6:'par1',
    select9:'par4',
    parities: ['par1,'par2','par3'],
    parities2: ['par4,'par5','par6']
   }
 computed : {
   availableParitiess() {
        if (this.exchanges === 'ex2'){
    return this.parities = parities2 ;
        }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please share a condesanbox link to your issue or replicate it any other way

Comment: i am looking for a general anwser , how to relate selections in VUE js.